# Angular notifier wont load css even if i follow the instructions from documentation, it is for angular 9 with notifier 6.0.1

Tags: angular, typescript

So i have a problem. Angular notifier css wont load no matter what i do..
I followd the instructions from the installer page but it doesnt work for me

```
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        ComponentsModule,
        RouterModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        NotifierModule.withConfig(customNotifierOptions),
    ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AdminLayoutComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],

const customNotifierOptions: NotifierOptions = {
    position: {
        horizontal: {
            position: 'right',
            distance: 12
        },
        vertical: {
            position: 'bottom',
            distance: 12,
            gap: 10
        }
    },
    theme: 'material',
    behaviour: {
        autoHide: 5000,
        onClick: 'hide',
        onMouseover: 'pauseAutoHide',
        showDismissButton: true,
        stacking: 4
    },
    animations: {
        enabled: true,
        show: {
            preset: 'slide',
            speed: 300,
            easing: 'ease'
        },
        hide: {
            preset: 'fade',
            speed: 300,
            easing: 'ease',
            offset: 50
        },
        shift: {
            speed: 300,
            easing: 'ease'
        },
        overlap: 150
    }
};
```

and the app.component.css has this:
@import '~angular-notifier/styles';

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You need add `@import "~angular-notifier/styles";` to `styles.css` file and **do not add to app.component.css**

Sample demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-notifier-demo

Comment: Thank you, I've been trying to make it work for hours

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `<notifier-container></notifier-container>`
at the bottom
of all the html pages where you want the notifications to be shown.

Comment: cant you load it in the root component in one go?